# Google Translate API in Python

Tags: python, google-translate

I know about the Google Translate API in python. However, in my data frame, there are only a few entries that have 'Hindi' language. How do I recognize the language of these records and then translate them to English.

Basically, I want to do the following.

`if !hindi, continue else translate from hindi to english.`

I am using this - https://pypi.org/project/googletrans/

Answer (score 0):

So, I realized that default is English. The translate command automatically converts other languages to English and if it is English, it stays as it is.